# Publishing a JMS Map Message to JMeter

Tags: jmeter, jms

I am trying to send Text and Map JMS Messages to JMeter using the option to upload the message as a file. While the Text Message is getting sent fine, my Map Message is not getting sent. This is the error I am getting

```
1476200492861,0,JMS Publisher,000,java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 
line must have 3 parts: ,Point to piont 1-1,,false,,0,1,1,0,0
```

Here is a sample Map Message

```
$Header:
JMSMessageID=ID:LRTPSDMMK3.E08570CF87913A8D:1051
JMSTimestamp=Thu May 26 14:35:18 231 BST 2016
JMSDestination=Queue[MyQueue]
JMSDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT
JMSPriority=4
$Properties:
Server=String:WSO2 Carbon Server
Content-Length=String:340
Date=String:Thu, 26 May 2016 13:35:17 GMT
Content-Type=String:text/xml;charset=UTF-8
$MapBody:
TY=String:9
```

I think the formatting of my sample file must be wrong, but I can't find an example of how a Map Message should look like in a file. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the formating of my message. According to the JMeter source code, JMeter requires 3 params to be separated by 2 commas. Formatting my sample to fit that criteria worked a charm.

```
for (String line : lines){
    String[] parts = line.split(",",3);
    if (parts.length != 3) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("line must have 3 parts: "+line);
    }
```